# Groovy: unwrapping named map arguments in method

Tags: groovy

I'm finding myself passing a lot of variables to my methods as named arguments as it makes things a lot clearer:

```
doFunction(name: 'Jack', age: 27)
```

now in doFunction I often find myself doing this:

```
doFunction(Map args) {

  if (args['name']) {
    def name = args['name'] 
    // do stuff with name 
  }
}
```

Is there a language feature to unwrap the Map to its respective parameters on the fly? I couldn't find anything like that. and if there wasn't, I'm curious as to why, it seems like this is the natural Groovy approach to boilerplate. 
I'd like a way to immediately check and work on the parameter if it exists, is there a cleaner way to do this? am I approaching Map arguments the wrong way entirely?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since there is no destructuring like e.g. in clojure, one way to work with maps like this would be using `with`.  Like:

```
void destruct(Map params) {
    params.with{
        if (name) {
            println "Hello $name"
        }
        if (age) {
            println "I am $age years old"
        }
    }
}

destruct name: "World", age: 4.54e9
// => Hello World
// => I am 4.54E+9 years old
destruct name: "Computer"
// => Hello Computer
```

Also on the nitpicking side: those are *no* named arguments (like e.g. in python).  It is just a syntactic sugar for passing maps.  E.g. it is short for `destruct([name: 'World'])` -- it will *not* work for a method `void destruct(String name, BigDecimal age)`

Comment: interesting! and thanks for the nitpicking comment, could you show me the Clojure way of doing this?

Comment: in clojure it would be something like: `let [{:keys [name age]} params]`.  a simple example to get the delegating working would be using an `Expando` as your superclass, which basically is a map backed storage class.